# Graphing Complex Number on Argand Diagram

Tags: complex-numbers

Can someone please answer me, HOW does $Im(z^2) = 4$ get graphed like this?

[image]

and not like a normal parabola?

Like $Re(z^2) = 4$

[image]

But of course on the Imaginary axis.

It has been eating my mind up - and I just can't explain why the graph does that. 
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please someone?

Comment: I think the graph wolframalpha has given me for Im(z^2) = 4 is wrong. That's impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this way and see if you're satisfied. If we let $z=x+iy$ so $$\text{Im}(z^2)=2xy,~~\text{Re}(z^2)=x^2-y^2$$ so you can simply plot $xy=2$ when $\text{Im}(z^2)=4$. The following plot is a conformal plot of $\text{Im}(z^2)-4$ in an interval:

[image]

Comment: but if xy = 2 , it gives you a completely new graph. It turns in to a hyperbola.

Comment: So are you saying WolframAlpha has screwed up its graphing for complex numbers, because it gave me the right answer for Real.

Comment: @MATHSUSER: I don't know Mathematica but the theoretical approach is correct. Maybe we should wait to get another point of views. ;-)

Comment: Alright, thanks though considering no one else is answering. But I think WolframAlpha has made a mistake with Its complex number graphing.